# R, for loop on data frame column and need value from an other

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following type of data frame:

```
   Gender FSIQ VIQ PIQ Weight Height MRIcount IQindicator
1  Female  133 132 124    118   64.5   816932           1
2    Male  140 150 124     NA   72.5  1001121           1
3    Male  139 123 150    143   73.3  1038437           1
4    Male  133 129 128    172   68.8   965353           1
5  Female  137 132 134    147   65.0   951545           1
6  Female   99  90 110    146   69.0   928799           0
```

My objective is to make 2 vectors, one with the MRIcount of which the IQindicator is 1 and the other for IQindicator is 0

I have written the following:

```
MRI_low <-c()
MRI_high <- c()
for (index in brain_data[,8]){
  if (index = 1){
    MRI_high <- append(MRI_high, MRIcount)
  } else {
    MRI_low <- append(MRI_low, MRIcount)
  }
}
```

How can I make this work?

for this example i would need:

> ```
> > MRI_low <-c(928799) MRI_high <-c(816932, 1001121, 1038437, 965353,
> > 951545)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use logical indexing. Assuming your data frame's name is df, one solution could be

```
MRI_high <- df$MRIcount[df$IQindicator == 1]
MRI_low  <- df$MRIcount[df$IQindicator == 0]
```

With the *$*-operator, you can access/extract on variable of your data frame. Then, you see the logical condition in brackets. This makes a vector consisting of TRUE where the stated condition holds and FALSE if it does not hold. If you index a vector with a logical vector, you keep the values with a TRUE.

Comment: What is the fundamental difference, between your version and the one of $jdobres

Comment: The answer of jdobres is similar. The difference is only that he uses the function subset whereas I only use pure logical conditions. I presume that for large data sets my solution could be a bit faster since I don't need a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, this would work:

```
MRI_low <- subset(df, IQindicator == 0)$MRIcount
MRI_high <- subset(df, IQindicator == 1)$MRIcount
```

There are more graceful ways to do it using some extra packages, but this should suffice for the base installation.

Comment: How does this differ from $stats_guy awnser

Comment: Mine uses `subset()` and stats_guy uses logical indexing. The two answers are equivalent.